# How to execute the multiple timers in different time interval using window scheduler....?

Tags: c#, .net

How to execute the  multiple timers in different time interval using window scheduler....?
Is it possible using this functionality in .net...?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's not neccessarily the best option. Your question is way to broad for this site. Please narrow down your question so it's specific enough for us to provide an answer.

Comment: Please take a moment to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then consider revising your question.

Comment: You mean *Task* scheduler? What's a window scheduler? It is also unclear which part of this functionality would you like to use in .NET. Use the Task scheduler through an API, or simply use timers?

Comment: Thanks for response <Groo> but my requirement is execute multiple timers in window service.....?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use single timer for different time intervals 
for example:

```
private void Form_Load()
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
    timer1.Start(); // Start timer, This will raise Tick event after 1 second
    OnTick(); // So, call Tick event explicitly when we start timer
}

Int32 counter = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnTick();
}

private void OnTick()
{
    if (counter % 1 == 0)
    {
        OnOneSecond();//Write your code in this method for one second
    }

    if (counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        OnTwoSecond();
    }

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but my requirement is  execute multiple timers in window scheduler...?

Comment: Check this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6507/NET-Scheduled-Timer